# Absolute positioned element on a scrollable parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to have an child element (something like a toolbar) of a parent element to be positiond on its bottom edge. The bahavior should be the same as using position fixed for the browser view.

I'm using absolute position right now. Everyting is perfect until the parent needs to scroll its content. Then the toolbar moves along with the rest of the parent's content.

Could somebody explain me why the toolbar moves?
Is it possible to achieve that task without need any javascript?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.mock {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.tool-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mock"></div>
  <div class="tool-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but element with fixed position is positioned relative to the viewport

Comment: the `tool-bar` is always _initially_ positioned at the bottom of the container as specified by the css. But since the container is scrollable due to lengthy content, the tool-bar maintains its _initial_ relative position to the viewport, which is why it scrolls along. Use `position:fix` to keep it at the bottom if u wish

Comment: I need to position the `.tool-bar` relative to the `.container` not relative to the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toolbar is inside the scrollable area, that's why it scrolled. Try this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="mock"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="tool-bar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.scroll { /* style of .container to scroll */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an interesting fiddle that may help you. They are using position:fixed and the divs are not nested:

http://jsfiddle.net/b2jz1yvr/

```
<div class="fixedContainer">
    This is experimental
</div>
<div class="otherContainer"></div>

.fixedContainer {
    background-color:#ddd;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 2em;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.otherContainer {
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#bbb
}
```